# Display text above or on video view in android

Tags: android, android-layout, android-videoview

I got a simple requirement. I have a user logged into my app using his email-id.
After logging in he plays a video which is played using VideoView.
I want to display the user's email id on the right hand side bottom corner just above the controls.
I am thinking on using a Framelayout and placing a text view above the video view. Is this the right approach? Or does VideoView provides some method internally to show text above video?
Also the way I am trying to show the text is this the best way?
Or can I do it in much simpler way?
Sorry if the question sounds noob I am new to android. Also there is not much help available on this topic so thought should ask you guys.

Regards,

digitalis

Comment: I think the best way is put a textview on videoview using framelayout or relative layout.

Comment: Show your code..!!

Comment: it's more design question rather than how to implement it

Answer (score 1):

RelativeLayout didn't work for me. Using LinearLayout is the only option I found.

```
<LinearLayout
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent">

        <VideoView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="440dp"
            android:id="@+id/howToUse_vv"
            android:scaleType="fitCenter"
            />

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/btnPlay"
            android:layout_width="70dp"
            android:layout_height="70dp"

            android:layout_gravity="center"
            android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"


            android:padding="5dp"

            android:clickable="true"
            android:focusable="true"
            android:onClick="playVideo"

            android:src="@mipmap/play" />
    </LinearLayout>
```

Answer (score 0):

Hi this is the way Biswajit suggested in his comment, try this out:

```
<RelativeLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <VideoView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent" />

    <TextView
        android:layout_centerInParent="true"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="foo"/>
</RelativeLayout>
```

Note, that order of the views is important. View placed in container after another view will be covering it so below will not work:

```
<RelativeLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <TextView  
        android:layout_centerInParent="true"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content" 
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="foo"/>

    <!--bad order VideoView is covering TextView-->
    <VideoView 
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent" />
</RelativeLayout>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
    <VideoView
        android:id="@+id/vv_question_video_solutions"
        android:layout_width="80dp"
        android:layout_height="40dp"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true" />

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_centerInParent="true"
        android:text="Video View" />
</RelativeLayout>
```

[image]